# Javascript to make a button take multiple action on an element

Tags: javascript, html, button, action

I currently have buttons that adjust the height, color, opacity of a box for example-

```
document.getelementbyID("growbutton").addEventlistener("click", function growFunction() {
  document.getelementbyID("box").style.height = "300px"
});

document.getelementbyID("bluebutton").addEventlistener("click", function blueFunction() {
  document.getelementbyID("box").style.color = "#0000FF"
});
```

Those work fine- What I want is a reset button, that will reset "box" back to original settings. Current JS looks like this.

```
document.getelementbyID("resetbutton").addEventlistener("click", function resetFunction() {
  document.getelementbyID("box").style.height = "150px"
});

document.getelementbyID("resetbutton").addEventlistener("click", function resetFunction() {
  document.getelementbyID("box").style.color = "#FFA500"
});
```

When executed however, the "box" only resets in height, but does not reset in color. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, please utilize the code formatter toolbar button {} so your code is legible.

Comment: How is the first block working fine where you have written `getelementbyID` instead of `getElementById`?

Comment: @adiga he probably manually copied it to here, instead of `ctrl+c`. Thats my guess

Comment: @iagowp why would they do that. Isn't it easier to copy the code here than write the whole thing manually again

Comment: @adiga, yes sorry. I'm super new to the whole coding thing. I'm starting a code bootcamp  later this year and I'm doing some practice assignments to learn ahead of time. I just manually typed it in.

Comment: @JohnTyner I will also utilize the code formatter.

Thanks everyone for the reply. I'll give these a try.

Comment: No worries. You can also [create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) in Stack Overflow. It has options to format your code. It will also show the errors in the console when you run it.

Comment: @adiga awesome, thank you for info and the patience while I learn :).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send a single action per function. You can create a function `resetFunction` and pass it to `addEventListener`.

```
function resetFunction(){
  let box = document.getElementById("box");
  box.style.height = "150px";
  box.style.color = "#FFA500";
}

document.getElementById("resetbutton").addEventlistener("click", resetFunction);
```

This is the best way, but probably changing the name of your second function to `resetFunction2` would also work

Comment: It's `getElementById` and `addEventListener`. I'd also recommend querying for `#box` once and setting the styles in one call.

Comment: I've just copied from the question, supposed it was correct. I'll fix it anyways, thanks

Comment: yeah I manually typed the code instead of copy pasting it because I'm at work at a different job at the moment and don't have my school laptop with me.

In Visual studio code- when I type function resetFunction(), that's defining and naming the function. Then the {
const box = document.getElementById("box"); is saying set the element named box constants. Then the following line define those constants?

Then the following line is saying on click do the function resetFunction? 

Am I understanding that correct?

Comment: my formatting in typing these responses is terrible, sorry. Thank you everyone :).

Comment: Ok, just copied this code and tried it. It still only resets the height?

Comment: @MichaelRogers is that a question or afirmation?

Comment: About your first comment, yes, define and name function, `let box...` create a reference to the DOM element so you don't need to query it twice (performance improvement). next lines put the values you want. last line passes the function to be executed when clicking, same thing you were doing

Comment: @iagowp er... a little of both I suppose. It is still only resetting height / why would that be happening?

Comment: by color you mean the color of the text or the background color? Check the console and see if there's any error. I've tried running it and its working fine

Comment: @MichaelRogers your problem could also be css specificity. To be sure, you could try  `box.style.color = "#FFA500 !important";` But thats not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

In effect you'll need to store a set of default values that you can refer to.
You can do this when the document loads, ie:

```
<head>
<script>
var defaults = {}
function setDefaults() {
  defaults.box = {
    height: document.getElementByID("box").style.height,
    color: document.getElementByID("box").style.color
  }

// I tucked these functions in here since they need to fire after the page loads

    document.getElementByID("resetbutton").addEventListener("click", function resetFunction() {
      document.getElementByID("box").style.height = defaults.box.height
      document.getElementByID("box").style.color = defaults.box.color
    });


}
</head>
<body onload='setDefaults()'>
...
```

Comment: var defaults = {}
function setDefaults() {
  defaults.box = {
    height: document.getElementByID("box").style.height = "150px",
    color: document.getElementByID("box").style.color = "#FFA500"
}

I edited your code here to define the height and color, does that look right?

Comment: @MichaelRogers - my intention was to read the values directly from the DOM rather than hard code the information. Since the original height and color would be defined in a stylesheet somewhere it doesn't make sense to hard code that data twice. If you update your stylesheet, this code will automatically adjust

Comment: Oh so I don't need to set the values, it will read it from the HTML document? Sorry for not understand inherently, still learning >.<.

Comment: Correct. It will read the HTML to get the default values

Comment: Ok the first suggestion by @iagowp, to create a function and pass to eventListener still only adjusts the height and not the color. I'm going to try try your solution, and see if that works.

Comment: I updated my answer to use just one click event listener for resetting...

Answer (score 0):

Ya'll are going to be really mad at me... Super noob mistake. The reset function would've been working this whole time with all of the JS that was posted. My color change button address backgroundcolor, my reset addresses color. It's fixed now!